# Is the engineering definition of redundancy commonly understood

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

In writing for non-technical people (C-suite, Board of Directors etc.), is it more likely this audience would understand redundancy to mean additional components to take over for failed components or would they interpreted to mean unnecessary or useless components?

If the second definition is more likely, what would be the alternative way of describing the components there to keep systems running in the event of a failure?

Comment: You should consult the Department of Redundancy Department.

Comment: If you think they might not understand its meaning, and/or think it's just biztalk, you should make a point of defining and discussing it before using it. Including implications and false conclusions. Redundancy is what makes language and learning and management possible in the first point; it's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: It is wise to avoid using *redundancy* in the engineering sense when communicating with those who are not familiar with the world of engineering, just as it is wise to avoid using *C-suite* when communicating with those who are not familiar with the world of management.

Comment: When executives hear "redundancy" they think about firing people.

Comment: Almost certainly not. Going sideways, most people's understanding of 'redundancy' applies to (un)employment and affects the employee, when in fact what's made redundant is the job.

Outside the scope of SE ELU, is it not clear that "This is a redundant system which…" is never necessary and can always be rephrased as "This is a system which…"?

Answer (score -3):

Although redundancy is common word and can be easily understood by common people too but you can use duplicate, unnecessary or useless too for the same.

Comment: This doesn't really address the particular meaning of redundancy that's mentioned in the question.

Comment: Those are the meanings he wants to avoid. Why would you recommend he use those words?